# Mean python pandas by values in a row

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a dataframe with with multiple rows similar to the one showed below:

```
  wave      cross cross2
0 299.0   1.25    3.30
1 299.5   1.30    4.20
2 300.0   1.45    4.36
3 300.5   1.65    4.32
4 300.8   1.56    4.56
```

What I want to do is to average the data for the same wavelengths so that is get a data frame with wave as an integer, which results in something like this:

```
  wave   cross cross2
0 299    1.30  3.75
1 300    1.55  4.41
```

what is the best way to achieve this with python pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggreagate `mean`, but first cast `wave` column to `int`:

```
df = df.assign(wave = df['wave'].astype(int)).groupby('wave').mean()
```

Or:

```
df['wave'] = df['wave'].astype(int)
df = df.groupby('wave').mean()
```

Or:

```
df = df[df.columns.difference(['wave'])].groupby(df['wave'].astype(int)).mean()
```

---

```
print (df)
         cross    cross2
wave                    
299   1.275000  3.750000
300   1.553333  4.413333
```

Comment: Yes. I was thinking of the 3rd one. Now 2nd. I think we can do it directly

Comment: @Sanne - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jezrael's great alternatives you can pass a column to groupby:

```
df = df.groupby(df['wave'].astype(int)).mean().drop('wave',1).reset_index()
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
wave      cross cross2
299.0   1.25    3.30
299.5   1.30    4.20
300.0   1.45    4.36
300.5   1.65    4.32
300.8   1.56    4.56'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df = df.groupby(df['wave'].astype(int)).mean().drop('wave',1).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   wave     cross    cross2
0   299  1.275000  3.750000
1   300  1.553333  4.413333
```